# Justify immoral deeds with one incapacitties

Tags: sila

Some suggested to take precepts not so serious, saying "The Buddhist teachings do not exist for you to create suffering for yourself." and approved kill by putting his happiness as more worthy then that of "lower".

Do this "Buddhist teachings" have any thing to do with the Buddhas and that of wise?

*[Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks, Buddh-ism but for release and might be not welcome for those seeking for trade.]*

Answer (score 1):

[Lonaphala Sutta: The Salt Crystal](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html) is about ungrateful monk ungrateful for alms food.

The people struggle to grow & find food but share their food with the monk.

If the drought comes, the people scavenge the sea shore for oysters, looking for food. What they collect they give a share to the monk.

The monk is fed for his livelihood of sharing wisdom with the people. When the people must scavenge for oysters, the monk offers forgiving wisdom to earn his wages of oyster food.

In Thailand, Sri Lanka, Burma & Vietnam, the fishermen share their catch with the monks. But the ungrateful monk offers condemnation rather than wise understanding of reality.

Lord Buddha said the monk is to be grateful for the smallest gift.

Precept of killing has a limit to its practise by humanity. It is a training precept.

Lord Buddha did not teach vegetarianism.

Comment: Seems to nothing as bias and total improper attention when ever touched DD's incapazities.. See MN97. The Buddha does not approve resting on incapacity, neith in regard of world nor in regard of liberation. And it all has not to do with eating but killing, there is a different. Be mindful, not ever biased.Political wishi washi... Nobody, nothing can force one to immorality aside ones incapacities to let go of desries

Comment: I want to mention that this is an interpretation (or application) of that sutta rather than a direct paraphrase of it.